# how to create trigger that add time when inserting record

Tags: mysql

I have table called race with a lap1, lap 2 and lap3 as the attribute. Now want to create a Trigger that will add the laps which has time as datatype. And also insert the added laps into the finish_time in the results table.[results table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjbxy.png)[race table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfUWO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. In real life, database server could have different time or different timezone configured. Or you can have bad timezone configured on your side when connection to database. It is always better use dates and times from PHP and don't rely on database settings until you have database fully under control.